# jQuery Filter Select Menu with rel value

Tags: jquery, regex, drop-down-menu, filter

I use this code to filter my `<select>` menu:

```
jQuery.fn.filterByText = function(textbox) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var select = this;
        var options = [];
        $(select).find('option').not('option:first-child').each(function() {
            options.push({value: $(this).val(), text: $(this).text(), rel: $(this).attr('rel')});
        });
        $(select).data('options', options);

        $(textbox).bind('change keyup', function() {
            var options = $(select).empty().data('options');
            var search = $.trim($(this).val());
            var regex = new RegExp(search,"gi");

            $.each(options, function(i) {
                var option = options[i];
                if(option.text.match(regex) !== null) {
                    $(select).append(
                        $('<option>').text(option.text).val(option.value)
                    );
                }
            });
        });
    });
};
```

As you can see, I use `.not('option:first-child')` to exclude the first `<option>` tag.

**I have 2 problems with this code, it works fine, but I need to include the `rel` attribute in my filtering and I want to re-add the `option:first-child` when I clear my textbox.**

I've added the `rel: $(this).attr('rel')` to my `options` array, but I'm not sure how to add it back to the filtered results?

Can I create `var original = [];` and push all of the original values into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include the rel attribute in your filtering, you almost did the job. Just add **`.attr('rel', option.rel)`**:

```
$('<option>').text(option.text).val(option.value).attr('rel', option.rel)
```

Instead of re-add the first `option`, you can just keep it, and remove the others:

```
$(select).children("option").not(":first").remove();
```

**Edit** *(how to retrieve the "data" attribute)*:

You can do like this (improvable using variables caching):

```
var options = $(select).data('options');
$(select).children("option").not(":first").remove();
```

or like this, to maintain chainability:

```
var options = $(select).children("option:not(:first)").remove().end().data('options');
```

**Edited answer**

```
$(select).children("option").not(":first")
$(select).find('option').not('option:first-child')
```

**children VS find:**

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only
>   travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse
>   down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren,
>   etc.) as well.

Since `options` are direct children of the `select` element, it's better to use children().

**:first VS :first-child**

> The :first pseudo-class is equivalent to :eq(0). It could also be
>   written as :lt(1). While this matches only a single element,
>   :first-child can match more than one: One for each parent.

We only have one parent (our `select`). So both work here.
**However, note that:**

> Because :first is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :first cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. To achieve the best performance when using :first to select
>   elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then
>   use .filter(":first") *(or here, .not(":first"))*.

As often, it's all depending on the situation / context.

Comment: `.attr('rel', option.rel)` worked perfectly. Will using: `$(select).children("option").not(":first").remove();` differ from using `$(select).find('option').not('option:first-child').each(function() {`?

Comment: @tdun I edited my answer. Some differences, but same result in this case.

Comment: Great, I'll explore this more, thanks a lot for the quick response!

Comment: I'm still not sure about the "reseting" of the select menu, I want to exclude my first option because it's kind of a place holder that says "Click to choose!" so I remove that from the filtering, but when I clear the text from the textbox, the "Click to choose!" doesn't come back as the default value...?

Comment: Figured it out, I used a portion of @webdeveloper's answer!

Comment: @tdun I was about to post this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/d3wsa/1/
glad your code works ! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this for attributes:

```
attr('rel', option.rel)
```

No need in `$('select').data('option')`, because you store them in array. Use object `caching`, no need for wrapping 3 times option to get 3 values.

Demo how it could look like: http://jsfiddle.net/BSDdZ/

Comment: +1 for a way to 're-add' the `option:first-child`, I used part of your answer in my solution! Thanks!

Comment: @tdun Not at all, have a nice day ;)